# Python what does if 'self.root' do?

Tags: python, if-statement, self

For example:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._root = None

def get(self, key):
    if self._root:
        return self._root.get(key).value
    raise KeyError
```

What does this `if self._root:` return? `self._root` is not a boolean.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html

Comment: Read this[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] to understand how to ask a good question.

Comment: This concept seems quite common in programming languages to say `if x` where `x` is not a boolean type, but where there is a conversion to boolean known to the language/compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to look at it.
The straight forward way to check what would happen is simple, just check the flow with a simple "if" statement.

```
>>> if None:
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
False
```

Now, for something that is more indicative, you can check a non "None" value and see what happens.

```
>>> a = "asf"
>>> if a:
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
True
>>> a = None
>>> if a:
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
False
```

So the if statement you got there checks if self._root is None or not, and calls a method of it if it's not None.

Answer (score 0):

Self._root can be thought of as being similar to index[0] when looking at object. Self._root is a way to tell the interpreter to look at a ***"root"*** of the items/objects being processed.

Answer (score -2):

it depend on what is self._root
for example:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None

    def get(self, key):
        if self._root:
            return self._root.get(key).value
        raise KeyError

class MyDict(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value

n=Node()
n._root={'key':MyDict('value')}
print(n.get('key'))  #the result is 'value'
```

Comment: You didn't explain your code, just gave an another example, which doesn't really help the user asking the question.

Comment: Explain the code maybe better.But I think the code is so simple that it is not necessary to be explained..And I would suggest the asker to Read this[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] to understand how to ask a good question.